# Doctrine Mapping DDD : Two or Many Entity to One Table Mapping on One Entity Manager

Tags: database-design, orm, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

I am following DDD and I have an Inquiry Context which have Marketer and Encoder entity. basically the two have the same data (they are the user of the system), but different logics (based on domain). I dont want to apply SINGLE TABLE INHERITANCE (it will add a discrimiator column) because the table will be used on another context.

On my code, The marketer have PersonName value object and a FOSUserBundle User

```
/**
 * Class Marketer
 * @package Elite\Model\Inquiry
 */
class Marketer
{

    private $userAccount;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(IdentityUser $userAccount, PersonName $name)
    {
        $this->userAccount = $userAccount;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

/**
 * The receiver of the inquiry
 * @package Elite\Model\Inquiry
 */
class Encoder
{
    public function __construct(IdentityUser $userAccount, PersonName $name)
    {
        parent::__construct($userAccount, $name);
    }

    /**
     * Make an inquiry for the inquirer
     *
     * @param Inquirer $inquirer The inquirer
     *
     * @param Marketer $marketer The marketer to be assigned to follow up
     * @param \DateTime $date The date of inquiry
     * @return Inquiry The inquiry
     */
    public function makeInquiry(Inquirer $inquirer, Marketer $marketer, \DateTime $date)
    {
        return new Inquiry($inquirer, $this->userAccount, $marketer, $date);
    }
}
```

How can I map the two entity on one table?

Is there a better design than what I currently have right now?

Does the Inquiry needs to have the Encoder on its constructor?

Should I instantiate the Inquiry outside the encoder? and just pass the instance of the FOSUSer to INquiry?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the books "Domain-Driven Design" of Eric Evans and "Implementing Domain-Driven Design" of Vaughn Vernon. DDD is not so much about data. So are you sure that Marketer and Encoder really belong to the same bounded contect and even aggregate especially if they are the users of the system regarding that users and authorization is normaly a seperate bounded context? Otherwise use value objects to represent the Marketer and Encoder. Use Entities only if really needed (maintaining identity if value changes). And couple them with one of the standard methods in the books to the users in the user context.

To answer your question about the one table: The thing that matches your "shared table" most closely in DDD is the "shared kernel". But it is considered a bad choice in more complex scenarios and should only be used with care. If user, marketer and encoder end up in different bounded contexts, they should be stored in different tables because every bounded context has its own data storage (at least in my understanding of DDD).